# Unsigned Release APK not installing

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, release, android-install-apk

Just asking if it's the intended way or a "bug": On Android Studio 3.3 I've generated an APK with *release* flavour, from

```
Build -> Build Bundle(s)/APK -> Build APK
```

then i clicked "locate" and drag and drop the apk (the name is clearly saying that is unsigned) on the emulator (API level PIE). The installation fails with "app not installed". Is there a way to install a unsigned release version? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you mean on phone or on emulator ? It should work on emulator, but to install on actual device you have to sign it .

Comment: Android doesn't allow unsigned APKs in general. I'm not sure about what @Jimmy said, but it's possible that a debug build of Android won't require signed APKs. However, if the emulator is running Google Play Services, it's not a debug version.

Comment: @TheWanderer Debug build is signed automatically with debug keystore. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode

Comment: So why can I generate unsigned release apk if I can't install it?

Comment: @Toris yes, but the OP didn't do that.

Comment: @Jumpa so that you can analyze it.

Comment: @TheWanderer thanks for your reply. What do you exactly mean by "analyze"?

Comment: `Build>>Analyze APK...`

Comment: @Jumpa You can generate unsigned release apk so that someone who is responsible and have rights will later sign it before publishing. It is not necessary that everyone on the development team have those rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it's not a bug.
Not allowing unsigned apks to install is one of security features. And unsigned apks have some use cases.

It's confusing but correct way ,for most of android app developers, to build a relase build, for public release, is Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK... .

Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) is for developpers and if signing setting is not set, it will generate unsigned apk. Signing setting can be set from File -> Project Structure... -> 
Modules/app -> Signing tab and Build Types tab -> release -> Signing Config.

Unsigned apk can also be signed with tools other than Android Studio. Publishers like Google, Amazon etc also do like this. They sign (wrap) apks with signatures other than the signatures which developpers have signed. "When to sign" is separated from build process, but it doesn't mean allowing unsigned apks to install on devices.

There are developper tools like [apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner), and it's one of tools. Developpers have rights to select signing tools. Unsigned apks are for them, I think.

Just for knowledge:
Some guys seems to find a way to temporally disable such security features like [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/application-signature-verification-how-it-works-how-to-disable-it-with-xposed-and-why-you-shouldnt/).